# Is this thing a method(java)?

Tags: java

Still in the early stages of learning Java and I saw the following in some code which I did not understand:

```
public class sprite {
     private Image image;

     public Sprite(Image image) {
          this.image = image;
     }
```

I'm not asking for an explanation of what the code is doing, I'm just curious what "public Sprite(..." is. Is it some kind of method? It doesn't declare a return type and it's not void.

Thanks for any responses. An actually explaination of what the code is really doing might be over my head I just want to know about the language construct.

Comment: It's an object constructor. You should really start from learning the basics...

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I'm on the fence. The first reason listed for down voting is *research effort*. Wouldn't this fit the bill? It's one of the most basic tenets of Java and OOP. If someone posted a question that said 'What does `if` do?` would you down vote it?

Comment: @BrianRoach: Quite possibly.  However, that's a lot easier to Google for than this syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a typo (i.e. assuming the first line is actually `public class Sprite {`), then that is a [**constructor**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).  It's used to initialise an object of type `Sprite`, so it doesn't return anything, so it's not a method.

It's invoked when you do something like:

```
Image image = ...;
Sprite s = new Sprite(image);  // Constructor called here
```

[If you don't have a typo, then it's not a constructor, it's simply invalid Java.]

Answer (score 3):

In java, a class method which doesn't declare a return type and carries the same name as the class is known as a constructor. It is the method that gets called when you make a new object.

```
public class Foo {
    private int bar;
    public Foo(int arg) {
        this.bar = arg;
    }
}

Foo f = new Foo(1);
```

would make a new instance of `Foo` and  set it's internal variable `bar` to 1

Answer (score 1):

It's a constructor.  It is a special method that instantiates an object of the class; typically it will set values, initialize any internal objects its uses. You can have multiple constructors, with different signature, for a class.

In this case, the constructor is public, and initializes the object's `image` property to the image passed to the constructor.

For more, [see this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Answer (score 1):

That's a constructor.

It allows you to create an instance of the `Sprite` class from a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a constructor. This is not a method.

More explanations here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html.
And good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

`public Sprite(Image image)` is a constructor for the class `Sprite`. It does any setup that might need to be done any time an instance of the class is created (like when you use the 'new' keyword), in this case, setting the `image` instance variable to the one passed by the caller in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It's a constructor. Note,that you should capitalize first letter of class Sprite